# How to play a growing audio file using the Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, web-audio-api, ytdl

I am creating a electron application that downloads a audio file, but, I want to play this audio file while it's downloading instead of waiting it to complete. Is that possible? Currently I am using this script to download:

```js
let file;
return new Promise((resolve) => {
    if (fs.existsSync(path.resolve(`musics/${musicName}.mp3`))) {
        resolve(path.resolve(`musics/${musicName}.mp3`));
    }

    ytdl(url, {
        filter: "audioonly",
    }).pipe((file = fs.createWriteStream(`musics/${musicName}.mp3`)));

    file.on("finish", () => {
        resolve(path.resolve(`musics/${musicName}.mp3`));
    });

    file.on("error", (err) => {
        console.log(err);
        resolve(false);
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you only want to play it or do you need to do something more from the WebAudioAPI? If the latter, what is it exactly? The obvious tools for this would be the [Media Source Extensions API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Source_Extensions_API), but it would require you serve your audio in an other format than mp3 (it needs to be fragmented) and also, to connect it to WebAudio later is a bit cumbersome (I believe it implies playing it in a MediaElement, then generating a mediaelementsourcenode...)

Comment: @Kaiido I need to play the audio file while it's downloading it (like youtube and spotify does)... For now, I need to wait the file to be fully downloaded to play it. I'll take a look in what you mentioned